# Creating an Async task Class that returns results from a parsed XML URL

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble turning my XML parsing code into an Async task class and I was wondering if anyone could help me with an example of how I could put it together. I am working with the Android Google Maps Demo Code and I want to parse a value from a URL that contains XML and display it when I touch the map. The map touching code is provided and shown below.

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    /*
    .......Code......
    */
    mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + new AsyncClass().execute(xmlURL));
}
```

Here is the code that parses the value I want from the URL that contains the XML...

```
double price = 0;

URL xmlContent= new URL("http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices");
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xmlContent.openStream()));
NodeList fuel = doc.getElementsByTagName("midgrade");
Element grade = (Element) fuel.item(0);
price = Double.parseDouble(grade.getTextContent());
```

I would like the variable "price" to be returned in the Async task class so I can call the class in this line of code, thus returning the value and displaying it when the screen is touched...

```
mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + new AsyncTaskClass().execute(xmlURL));
```

If someone could show and explain how to create a Async class that does such a thing, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of something being *asynchronous* is to start it off, normally as a result of some UI action, then let it run in the background, and then finally update the UI (on the UI thread) when it's finished.  This

```
mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + new AsyncClass().execute(xmlURL));
```

looks like you're attempting to execute the async task when the map is clicked, and immediately get back a result to display in the `mTapTextView`.  Try something like this:

```
 private class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Double> {
     protected Double doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(urls[0].openStream()));
         NodeList fuel = doc.getElementsByTagName("midgrade");
         Element grade = (Element) fuel.item(0);
         return Double.parseDouble(grade.getTextContent());         
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Double price) {
         mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + price);  // TODO: probably a typo in your string literal?
     }
 }
```

and then use it like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    /*
    .......Code......
    */
    URL xmlURL = new URL("http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices");
    new AsyncTaskClass().execute(xmlURL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of `AsyncTask`

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Double> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(URL... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//do your work here
    return something;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
       // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + String.valueOf(result));
```

}

Put all of your parsing in `doInBackground()` and return that value which `onPostExecute()` will take. There you can call `setText(result);` on your `TextView`.

Call your `AsyncTask` from your `onClick()` or wherever you need to like

```
TalkToServer task = new TalkToServer();  // in case you need a constructor with params
task.execute(xmlURL);
```

Assuming this is an inner class of your `MainActivity` and `mTapTextView` is a member variable you will have access to it. This might not be complete code but would give you a good idea of how to do it. You may need to tweak a couple things depending on your set up.

If you don't want the user to be able to do anything else while this is happening then you may want to add a `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()` and `dismiss()` it in `onPostExecute()`